# Typing keys when using with t useTranslation hook

Tags: react-i18next

I'm trying to bring type safety to usage of the t function, from the useTranslation hook. I've seen the following thread which expands on the Resources interface but I think it's not exactly what I'm trying to do.

https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/1280

What I would like to do is the following:

```
// namespaces - A, B, both have key "hello"

import { useTranslation, TranslationKeys } from 'react-i18next';

export function Blah() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return <div>{t(TranslationKeys.hello)}</div>;
}
```

I don't want us as developers to be aware of different namespaces, just to deal with a single merged set of keys. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per: https://react.i18next.com/latest/typescript#create-a-declaration-file

We have 3 namespaces - sport, common and stuff in order of important to least important.

For the TS typings we just merged the contents into the `sport` namespace which is also the default and this has done fine.

```
declare module 'react-i18next' {
  interface Resources {
    'sport': typeof sport & typeof common & typeof stuff;
  }
}
```